# Ignore the rest of the line read after using file.readline(size)

Tags: python, security

I <s>have got</s> **had an issue**.

I have a Python application that will be deployed in various places. So Mr Nasty will highly likely tinker with the app.

So the problem is security related. The app will receive a file (plain text) received from a remote source. The device has a very limited amount of RAM (Raspberry Pi).

It is very much possible to feed extremely large input to the script which would be a big trouble.
I want to avoid reading each line of the file "as is" but rather read just the first part of the line limited to eg. 44 bytes and ignore the rest.

So just for the sake of the case a very crude sample:

```
lines = []
with open("path/to/file.txt", "r") as fh:
    while True:
        line = fh.readline(44)
        if not line:
            break
        lines.append(line)
```

This works, but in case a line is longer than 44 chars, the next read will be the rest of the line, or multiple 44 byte long parts of the same line even. 
To demonstate:

```
print(lines)
['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \n', 
 '11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 
 '111111111111111111111111111111111111111\n', 
 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 
 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n', 
 '22222222222222222222222222222222222222222\n',
 'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc', 
 'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc', 
 'cccc\n', 
 '333333333333\n', 
 'dddddddddddddddddddd\n']
```

This wouldn't save me from reading the whole content to a variable and potentially causing a neat **DOS**.

I've thought that maybe using `file.next()` would jump to the next line.

```
lines = []
with open("path/to/file.txt", "r") as fh:
    while True:
        line = fh.readline(44)
        if not line:
            break   
        if line != "":
            lines.append(line.strip())
            fh.next()
```

But this throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 7, in <module>
    line = fh.readline(44)
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

...of which I can't do much about.
I've read up on `file.seek()` but that really doesn't have any capability as such what so ever (by the docs).

**Meanwhile, I was writing this article, I've actually figured it out myself. It's so simple it's almost embarrassing. But I thought I will finish the article and leave it for others whom may have the same issue.**

So my solution:

```
lines = []
with open("path/to/file.txt", "r") as fh:
    while True:
        line = fh.readline(44)
        if not line:
            break
        lines.append(line)
        if '\n' not in line:
            fh.readline()
```

So the output now looks like this:

```
print(lines)
['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
'11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111',
'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
'22222222222222222222222222222222222222222\n',
'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc',
'333333333333\n',
'dddddddddddddddddddd\n']
```

Which is the close enough.

I don't dare to say it's the best or a good solution, but it seems to do the job, and I'm not storing the redundant part of the lines in a variable at all.

**But just for the sake of curiosity, I actually have a question.**
As above:

```
fh.readline()
```

When you call such a method without redirecting its output to a variable or else, where does this store the input, and what's its lifetime (I mean when is it going to be destroyed if it's being stored at all)?

## Thank you all for the inputs. I've learned a couple of useful things.

I don't really like the way as `file.read(n)` works, even though most of the solutions rely on it.

Thanks to you guys I've come up with an improved solution of my original one using only `file.readline(n)`:

```
limit = 10
lineList = []
with open("linesfortest.txt", "rb") as fh:
    while True:

        line = fh.readline(limit)
        if not line:
            break

        if line.strip() != "":
            lineList.append(line.strip())
        while '\n' not in line:
            line = fh.readline(limit)

print(lineList)
```

If my thinking is correct, the inner while loop will read the same chunks of the line until it reads the EOL char, and meanwhile, it will use only a  sized variable again and again.
And that provides an output:

```
['"Alright,"', 
 '"You\'re re', 
 '"Tell us!"', 
 '"Alright,"', 
 'Question .', 
 '"The Answe', 
 '"Yes ...!"', 
 '"Of Life,', 
 '"Yes ...!"', 
 '"Yes ...!"', 
 '"Is ..."', 
 '"Yes ...!!', 
 '"Forty-two']
```

From the content of

```
"Alright," said the computer and settled into silence again. The two men fidgeted. The tension was unbearable.
"You're really not going to like it," observed Deep Thought.
"Tell us!"
"Alright," said Deep Thought.
Question ..."
"The Answer to the Great
"Yes ...!"
"Of Life, the Universe and Everything ..." said Deep Thought
"Yes ...!" "Is ..." said Deep Thought, and paused.
"Yes ...!"
"Is ..."
"Yes ...!!!...?"
"Forty-two," said Deep Thought, with infinite majesty and calm.
```

Comment: if there's a very big line, `readline` can create a big string and crash python because of out of memory. If there's a chance that you have very big lines, you have to read char by char and discard the end of lines

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that.

Comment: It’s not clear which of your two questions you’re asking here. You should post two separate questions: one with your original problem, which you can then post an answer to (and either accept your own answer, or wait and see if you get an even better one), and one with the new, completely independent question you can up with.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point you’ve already got answers to both of your questions here, so whichever one you edit this one to be, you’ve made one answerer’s answer invalid. So you should post a comment on whichever answer that is linking them to the new question and asking them to move their answer over there.

Comment: Let me add my experience with the solutions. While all solution works fine on my Intel CPU desktop running Ubuntu 18.04 . The Raspberry Pi 3 meta B with Raspbian 8 Jessie hangs both on `if not line.endswith("\n"): while fh.readline(1) != "\n": pass` and `while '\n' not in line: line = fh.readline(limit)` Meaning the script stuck, doesn't get passed the line = fh.readline(limit) after the first iteration. but it does work with `if '\n' not in line: fh.readline()`

Comment: I wonder what could be the use case of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just do:

```
f.readline()
```

a line is read from the file, and a string is allocated, returned, then discarded.

If you have very large lines, you could run out of memory (in the allocation/reallocation phase) just by calling `f.readline()` (it happens when some files are corrupt) even if you don't store the value.

Limiting the size of the line works, but if you call `f.readline()` again, you get the remainder of the line. The trick would be to skip the remaining chars until a line termination char is found. A simple standalone example of how I'd do:

```
max_size = 20
with open("test.txt") as f:
    while True:
        l = f.readline(max_size)
        if not l:
            break   # we reached the end of the file
        if l[-1] != '\n':
            # skip the rest of the line
            while True:
                c = f.read(1)
                if not c or c == "\n":  # end of file or end of line
                    break
        print(l.rstrip())
```

That example reads the start of a line, and if the line has been truncated (when it doesn't end by a line termination, that is), I read the rest of the line, discarding it. Even if the line is very long, it doesn't consume memory. It's just dead slow.

About combining `next()` and `readline()`: those are concurrent mechanisms (manual iteration vs classical line read) and they mustn't be mixed because the buffering of one method may be ignored by the other one. But you can mix `read()` and `readline()`, `for` loop and `next()`.

Comment: It’s only kept in `_` if the line was executed in interactive mode. If it’s part of a module (or a function, etc.), the value isn’t store anywhere; it becomes garbage immediately (and so in CPython it’s cleaned up immediately, but obviously that’s CPython-specific).

Comment: right! some interpreters even discard them immediately. Editing

Comment: Thanks! Solid argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
'''
$cat test.txt 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
'''
from time import sleep # trust me on this one

lines = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as fh:
    while True:
        line = fh.readline(44)
        print (line.strip())
        if not line:
            #sleep(0.05)
            break
        lines.append(line.strip())
        if not line.endswith("\n"):
            while fh.readline(1) != "\n":
                pass
print(lines)
```

Quite simple, it will read 44 characters, and if its not ending in new line it will read 1 character at the time till it gets to it to avoid large chunks into the memory, only then will it go to process next 44 characters and append them to the list.

Dont forget to use `line.strip()` to avoid getting `\n` as a part of the string when its shorter than 44 characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're asking your original question here, and not your side question about temporary values (which [Jean-François Fabre has already answered nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51329546/908494)).

Your existing solution doesn't actually solve your problem.

Let's say your attacker creates a line that's 100 million characters long. So:

- You do a `fh.readline(44)`, which reads the first 44 characters.
- Then you do a `fh.readline()` to discard the rest of the line. This has to read the rest of the line into a string to discard it, so it uses up 100MB.

You could handle this by reading one character at a time in a loop until `'\n'`, but there's a better solution: just `fh.readline(44)` in a loop until `'\n'`. Or maybe `fh.readline(8192)` or something—temporarily wasting 8KB (it's effectively the same 8KB being used over and over) isn't going to help your attacker.

For example:

```
while True:
    line = fh.readline(20)
    if not line:
        break
    lines.append(line.strip())
    while line and not line.endswith('\n'):
        line = fh.readline(8192)
```

In practice, this isn't going to be that much more efficient. A Python 2.x file object wraps a C stdio `FILE`, which already has a buffer, and with the default arguments to `open`, it's a buffer chosen by your platform. Let's say your platform uses 16KB.

So, whether you `read(1)` or `readline(8192)`, it's actually reading 16KB at a time off disk into some hidden buffer, and just copying 1 or 8192 characters out of that buffer into a Python string.

And, while it obviously takes more time to loop 16384 times and build 16384 tiny strings than to loop twice and build two 8K strings, that time is still probably smaller than the disk I/O time.

So, if you understand the `read(1)` code better and can debug and maintain it more easily, just do that.

---

However, there might be a better solution here. If you're on a 64-bit platform, or your largest possible file is under 2GB (or it's acceptable for a file >2GB to raise an error before you even process it), you can `mmap` the file, then search it as if it were a giant string in memory:

```
from contextlib import closing
import mmap

lines = []
with open('ready.py') as f:
    with closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as m:
        start = 0
        while True:
            end = m.find('\n', start)
            if end == -1:
                lines.append(m[start:start+44])
                break
            lines.append(m[start:min(start+44, end)])
            start = end + 1
```

This maps the whole file into *virtual* memory, but most of that virtual memory is not mapped to *physical* memory. Your OS will automatically take care of paging it in and out as needed to fit well within your resources. (And if you're worried about "swap hell": swapping out an unmodified page that's already backed by a disk file is essentially instantaneous, so that's not an issue.)

For example, let's say you've got a 1GB file. On a laptop with 16GB of RAM, it'll probably end up with the whole file mapped into 1GB of contiguous memory by the time you reach the end, but that's also probably fine. On a resource-constrained system with 128MB of RAM, it'll start throwing out the least recently used pages, and it'll end up with just the last few pages of the file mapped into memory, which is also fine. The only difference is that, if you then tried to `print m[0:100]`, the laptop would be able to do it instantaneously, while the embedded box would have to reload the first page into memory. Since you're not doing that kind of random access through the file, that doesn't come up.